# Microsoft Clarity on SharePoint 2016 On-Premises

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, master-page, web-analytics

Has anyone implemented Microsoft Clarity Analytics on SharePoint 2016 On-premises?

I have tried adding the Microsoft provided code by adding it into the  section of Master Page (Seattle), but the script does not appear to execute.

I have also tried moving the script into a separate file and loading it with an SPM tag but still no success.

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="/Style Library/js/clarity.js"/>
```

Any tips or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the tracking code to the `<head>` section. More information can be found here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/clarity-setup